# obj C BOOL evaluation confuses me

Tags: objective-c, boolean

This works:

```
    BOOL isFree = [[[record.scheduleData objectAtIndex:_displayedWeekdayIndex] objectAtIndex:i] boolValue];

    if (isFree == 1) {

        NSLog(@"%@ %i", record.author, i);
```

This doesn't:

```
    BOOL isFree = [[[record.scheduleData objectAtIndex:_displayedWeekdayIndex] objectAtIndex:i] boolValue];

    if (isFree) {

        NSLog(@"%@ %i", record.author, i);
```

Can someone explain why comparing the boolean with an integer gives the results I expect, but using `if(boolValue)` or `if(boolVal == YES)` always evaluates to false?

Comment: `if (isFree)` is the best option (because of the breadth of truth). For that to not work and `if (isFree == 1)` to work should not happen. What do you get if you log `isFree` ? And is this coming from an `NSNumber` or `NSString` ?

Comment: Your assessment is incorrect — there's no way the former can evaluate to true if the latter doesn't. They could differ in evaluating to false, e.g. if `isFree == 2`, but that's not what you're alleging. Please post your full method and remove all references to external code.

Comment: What is the value of `[[record.scheduleData objectAtIndex:_displayedWeekdayIndex] objectAtIndex:i]` before the `boolValue`?

Comment: And what platform and architecture are you using?

Comment: Tommy, boolValue will always return 0 or 1 (NO or YES), even if applied to an NSNumber with a different value.

Comment: Have you tried to step through the code with the debugger and see what the variable actually contain?

Comment: NSLog the value as a `%d`.

Answer (score 0):

Given this short piece of code, I don't know, and maybe this isn't related, but I've encountered similar behaviors in ObjC code that was mixed with C++. I'm wondering if your code is a little more complicated than this. Are these lines really back-to-back like this in the same file? Or is `isFree` returned and checked elsewhere? Is `isFree` ever passed by reference?

In my case, the issues came from redefining `BOOL`. In particular, there was a header file that did this:

```
#undef BOOL
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define BOOL bool 
#else
#define BOOL int
#endif
```

This led to madness because sometimes `BOOL` could be one byte, and sometimes it could be 4 bytes, and it would cause the compiler to manage function calls incorrectly. In many cases it kind of worked, but if a `BOOL` was passed by reference, it would explode and you'd wind up with things like `true != !false`.

My theory doesn't exactly match the code you've posted, but I suspect there's more going on in your code than just these couple of lines.

And as an aside, never redefine `BOOL`. And never define a type in a header differently based on being C++.